# How to reset push notification badge counter with PushWoosh on an iOS app

Tags: ios, push-notification, push, counter, badge

I sent a push notification to my users with PushWoosh, and manually set the badge counter to "1" (in the Advanced form).
Now the problem is the badge counter is stuck on "1" no matter if the user opened the app or even clicked the notification they got. This badge counter is very annoying to my users, so I need to find a solution as soon as possible.

What can I do to reset it and make it disappear?

Answer (score 3):

This should reset the badge regardless of push vendor when placed in  `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: But I'm talking about the current situation where the badge number is stuck. I need a quick solution, without fixing the code and resubmitting to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently sending another Advanced push, and putting "0" in the "Badges" field reset the counter and the problem is now solved.
Anyway, as suggested by jaytr0n, the code must be fixed to know how to handle this autonomously.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IclCv.jpg